# Autofs starting but seemingly doing nothing - not even logging?

Tags: linux

I am attempting to automatically mount a NTFS formatted usb raid array when inserted using autofs, but am finding that no mounting - in fact, not even an attempt to mount - is taking place.  I can't even seem to get anything to show up in the logs.  I'm quite confused.

I have a symbolic link created so that when I insert the drive it is automatically mapped to /dev/usbraid.  Now I just need it to auto mount that device to somewhere on the file system.

I am using picuntu (a stripped-down debian distro) on a Rikomagic MK802III.

I've installed autofs using apt-get, and I edited the /etc/auto.master file to read as follows:

```
+auto.master
/media    /etc/auto.removable
```

And my /etc/auto.removable file reads as follows:

```
/media/usbraid  -fstype=ntfs  :/dev/usbraid
```

I'm successfully able to start the service, but I see no feedback indicating that the auto.master file has been read or that an attempt to mount has taken place.  When I call 'service autofs status' I get the cursory 'auto fs start/running' message.

I expected at least an error or something.  In desperation, I modified the '/etc/default/autofs' file to set 'LOGGING="verbose"', but I still see nothing in any of the logs except a system log when the autofs service is started and stopped.

I'm obviously doing something wrong but can't quite figure out what.  Any ideas?

Comment: I meant to mention that I am successfully able to mount this drive manually by calling 'mount -t ntfs /dev/usbraid /mnt/usbraid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this one nailed down, thanks to some information from here: http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,13/func,view/id,14038/

Basically, the issue is that the autofs4 module isn't loaded.  If I run

```
modprobe autofs4
```

Says that the module isn't found.  It appears that the autofs module wasn't compiled into my kernel.  I suppose I can recompile the kernel, but this is probably more effort than it is worth.

Comment: Oh and I realize that this should have been on Server Fault and not Stack Overflow.  My bad.